# Is "Find a basis for the column space of $A$" and "Find a basis for Col $A$" asking the same thing?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is "***Find a basis for the column space of $A$***" and "***Find a basis for Col $A$***" asking the same thing?

Basically my question, it may seem stupid. I'm just curious though I'm trying to make sure I understand exactly what is being asked

Comment: I would assume they're the same.  What book are you using?

Comment: Lin Alg & it's App 5th Ed, -Lay http://whitemyth.com/sites/default/files/downloads/UniDocs/Linear%20Algebra%20and%20Its%20Applications%204E%20(Lay).pdf

Comment: I think your question really is "What does Col A" mean? Well, the answer to that obviously depends on your book, so I would try to go back and figure out where they first started using and/or defined Col A.

Though, practically speaking I can't imagine anyone using Col A to refer to anything but the column space of A in your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "$\operatorname{Col} A$" *is* the column space of $A$, so finding a basis for one is the same as finding the basis for the other.

Comment: Is $v$ in NullA the same as asking is $v$ a **basis** for Col $A$?

Comment: @Yusha No. "$v \in \operatorname{Null}(A)$" means $Av = 0$. Also, a single vector $v$ is not a basis of anything. A _set_ $\{v\}$ containing a single vector can be the basis of a column space. But $\{v\}$ being a basis for the column space of $A$ and $v$ being an element of $\operatorname{Null} A$ are about as opposite in meaning as you can get: Any vector in $\operatorname{Null} A$ is orthogonal to any vector in $\operatorname{Col} A$ (and specifically to any vector in a basis you've chosen), so the only vector that can ever be in both is $0$.